# C# equivalent of AtlEscapeUrl

Tags: c#, c++, atl

I am looking to mimic the behavior of this pair of [ATL functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zxk65xx(v=vs.120).aspx): AtlEscapeUrl / AtlUnescapeUrl.

Answer (score 2):

I expect you are looking for [`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Normally accessed via a property of the current controller/page but also available as `HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode`.